# Data type mismatch in criteria expression bypass

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, jet

I run a query on Access and although it warns me about null fields, it can still run the query and add the rows.

However, when I run through JET in VB.NET, it says "Data type mismatch in criteria expression".

Is there a way for JET to behave like Access (ie. still run the query and add the rows)?

I know I can convert the field to correct type in VB.NET and loop round, but I don't have the time for this as I need to do this on many different queries.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What interface are you using to execute your SQL? And how do you know that the results in Access are correct? Access allows inconsistent updates so you might never know what the problems are that have been discarded. My recommendation is to ELIMINATE whatever it is that's producing the errors and then you won't have any issues.

Comment: Yes, normally that is what I would do: Ensure the data is correct when inserting into database. However, I have not made this database, and it has many tables. I don't want to make any changes to the database structure. As mentioned in the OP, I'm using JET to execute the SQL. And I know the Access results are correct because it does do an insert whereas through JET it does not.

Comment: You don't have to change the data to avoid the problem -- just write your SQL statement to get rid of whatever problem is throwing the errors.

Comment: Access permits stuff like NULL values and it chops of text if length is greater (after prompts). Through JET, this yields errors. Like I said, there are literally hundreds of queries and tables, and it would be a pain to go through each of them and fix it. I want to maintain the existing db structure, but do it through JET/VB.NET rather than Access.

Comment: I don't think you've explained the situation very well at all. At this point I have nothing to offer, since you haven't made clear what the situation is. I can't conceive of a situation where the SQL would not throw a prompt within Access and then allow inconsistent updates. THIS IS A BAD THING, since it's not predictable what the results are. The fact that there's a lot of work to be done does not change one bit the fact that you can write your SQL to avoid the errors. If you're going to execute it from outside Access, you really have no choices.

Answer (score 0):

I would start looking at the fields that you have criteria for, then make your select statement in your query so that the nulls are changed to an acceptable type (try IsNull or NZ) or do a derived table (sub query) that eliminates the nulls before the criteria are processed.

For example

```
SELECT TextField, DateField, OtherField 
FROM Table 
WHERE TextField='something' And Datefield=#2/11/2011#
```

Here is a derived table solution:

```
SELECT TextField, DateField, OtherField
FROM ( 
    SELECT TextField, DateField, OtherField 
    FROM Table 
    WHERE TextField Is Not Null And Datefield Is Not Null
     ) AS aTable
WHERE TextField='something' And Datefield=#2/11/2011#
```

Natively you could say:

```
SELECT nz(Table.TextField,'') AS TextField...
```

Hope that helps